# Ajax code stops after first calculation

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I'm working on ajax code that calculate fees.
It work fine, but if I enter a second operation it stops.

```
<script>
var weight =   document.getElementById("weight").value;
var ship_type = document.getElementById("ship_type").value;
var eol = document.getElementById("eol").value;
function showFees(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  if (weight === 0) {
    document.getElementById("txtHint").innerHTML = "no thing";
    return;
  } else {
    var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
    document.getElementById("txtHint").innerHTML = this.responseText;
    }
    };
    xmlhttp.open("GET", "sdr.php?weight=" + weight + "&ship_type=" + ship_type + "&eol=" + eol, true);
    xmlhttp.send();
  }
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is because you are getting input values outside your function and it loads values first time and same data is fetched again and again when `showFees` function is called. Try below code to solve this,

```
var objWeight =   document.getElementById("weight");
var objShip_type = document.getElementById("ship_type");
var objEol = document.getElementById("eol");
function showFees(e) {
  var weight =   objWeight.value;
  var ship_type = objShip_type.value;
  var eol = objEol.value;
  e.preventDefault();
  if (weight === 0) {
    document.getElementById("txtHint").innerHTML = "no thing";
    return;
  } else {
    var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
    document.getElementById("txtHint").innerHTML = this.responseText;
    }
    };
    xmlhttp.open("GET", "sdr.php?weight=" + weight + "&ship_type=" + ship_type + "&eol=" + eol, true);
    xmlhttp.send();
  }
}
```

Comment: Welcome. In future you should clear your problem in question like you are calling `showFees` multiple times and there is no change in response. So that SO users will answer it without having any confusion.